# Increase size of Facebook Like Button

Tags: css

I am developing a feature where I want to increase the size(width and height) of Facebook Like button which is getting rendere on my page.

I have tried overidding the css but it is not working as my css is loading very late.

Help required.

Comment: PS, accept answers to some previous questions and people will be more generous with their answers.

Comment: something like `facebooklikebutton.style.width = whatever`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the correct overrides in your CSS? If I'm not mistaken, it doesn't matter when the CSS is loaded, just that it is loaded.
Be sure to check your CSS includes in the header file to make sure you're using the latest version. Also double check the classes or ids you need to override.

Perhaps you could post the code containing the like button you're trying to manipulate. If you're loading it in via Javascript you can use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/) or other Web Inspectors to find out the actual HTML that gets inserted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the css MUST be interpreted by the browser before the html element it refers to is loaded...
Second, the reason you can't select the button through CSS directly, is because it is rendered inside an iFrame that is controlled by the Facebook framework (you can check this out with firebug or any other inspector).

I'm not sure if it's feasible, but you have two possible ways to do it:

1. use javascript and the DOM to access inside that iFrame, select the button and style it.
2. create a button yourself, and give it the same href as the one generated originally, thus losing the fan-counter capabilities and whatever else is part of their framework